# Laravel, how to get last order date by user id

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables, users, orders and rewards, All I want is to get the last order created date and the total of rewards belong to user, I tried this code but it shows  wrong result

[image]

here for user_id 1 it shows the points 1073 but it must be 1073+190+190

and for order I want to see only the last created date if user have many orders, so I want to know when the last order was
thank you

```
public function getUserInfo()
{
    return $this
        ->leftJoin('rewards', $this->table . '.id', '=', 'rewards.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('orders', $this->table . '.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select
        (
            $this->table . '.*',
            'rewards.points as points',
            'orders.created_at as lastorderdate'

        )->groupBy('users.id')
        ->get();    
}
```

Comment: Didn't you try `orderby` created_at? it that works?

Comment: I tried ->orderBy('userorders.created_at','asc') but the same result (asc & desc)

Comment: `Model::latest()->first(); `

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in many ways, but the following is what I use these days.

wrap your `$lastOrder` into a subquery and join the subquery with the main query.

```
$lastOrder = DB::table('orders')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);

return $this
       ->leftJoin('rewards', $this->table . '.id', '=', 'rewards.user_id')
       ->leftJoinSub($lastOrder,'orders', function ($join){
             $join->on($this->table.'id', '=', 'orders.user_id');
        })->select(
            $this->table . '.*',
            'rewards.points as points',
            'orders.created_at as lastorderdate'
        )->groupBy('users.id')
        ->get();
```

Documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins) Note that subquery joins are a recent addition to laravel.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usersid' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `rewards`.`points` as `points`, `orders`.`created_at` as `lastorderdate` from `users` left join `rewards` on `users`.`id` = `rewards`.`user_id` left join (select * from `orders` order by `created_at` desc limit 1) as `orders` on `usersid`

Comment: there is no column named `user_id`? check for any typos?

Comment: the columns name are user_id, but dont know where this userid come from

Comment: I think there is a mistake plz help me thnkx